# Generate list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm try to make a list of the values `n,n+1,...2*n-1`
for example if I have `n=4 ==> [4,5,6,7]`

I have managed to write this code but **it shows the list of first n elements**. Can you help me modify it?

```
create(N,L):-
   create_list(N,[],L).

create_list(0,L,L).         
create_list(N,R,L):-
   N>0,
   N1=N-1,
   create_list(N1,[N|R],L).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing 'in reverse', in a certain sense. Try

```
create(N,L):-
    M is 2*N,
    create_list(N,M,L).

create_list(N,M,[N|R]):-
    N < M,
    N1 = N+1, % note: check if your Prolog accepts is/2 instead
    create_list(N1,M,R).
create_list(M,M,[]).
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could write a **logically pure** version of `create/2` based on `list_from_to/3`, defined in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30047316/4609915) to question "[Fill list in SWI-Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792730/fill-list-in-swi-prolog)":

```
create(From,Zs):-
   To #= 2*From-1,
   list_from_to(Zs,From,To).
```

Here the query you had in your question:

```
?- create(4,Zs).
Zs = [4,5,6,7] ;
false.
```

As `create/2` is pure, it is versatile and can also be used in different ways:

```
?- create(N,[4,5,6,7]).
N = 4.

?- create(N,[4,_,_,_]).
N = 4.
```